# c# Alternative fast methods of getting edge co-ordinates of an irregular object?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm currently having an issue finding a good algorithm to get the co-ordinates of every outer edge point of an object, which unfortunately can be complex and contain inner regions.

---

### [image]

I've got a list of points containing every pixel point of an object already produced from a connected component labeling algorithm. This has allowed me to check each co-ordinate around each pixel in the image and if one is not present then I know its a gap or edge through the following.

```
public List<IntPoint> SquareSearch(List<IntPoint> ListOfPoints, IntPoint point)
{
    List<IntPoint> UnfoundPixels = new List<IntPoint>();

    int MoveX = point.X;
    int MoveY = point.Y;

    for (int LTR = MoveX - 1; LTR <= MoveX + 1; LTR++)
    {
        for (int TTB = MoveY - 1; TTB <= MoveY + 1; TTB++)
        {
            if (ListOfPoints.IndexOf(new IntPoint(LTR, TTB)) == -1)
            {
                if ((LTR > -1) && (TTB > -1))
                {
                   UnfoundPixels.Add(new IntPoint(LTR, TTB));
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

However going through this process is very slow and proportional to the size of each object since it has to be repeated for every pixel in the object. Any suggestions on an alternative method?

Comment: can you add your result picture?

Comment: Did you tried [Detecting some simple shapes in images][1]  [1]:http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/

Comment: Yes, I have looked into AForge and unfortunately its main algorithm scans the image by row and column looking for the smallest and largest x and y values which is good if you don't have shapes that fold in on themselves, if they do it misses a whole segments of shapes.

Comment: Also I'm not returning an image I'm after a list of edge points.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question completely. Would it solve your problem to, say, start at the topmost pixel in your connected region and then follow the outer contour all the way around? I think I might even be able to find some old C# code in which I implemented a fairly standard contour-following algorithm for just this purpose, if that's what you want.

Comment: That is what has been suggested below but its not as simple as just following the contours as some edges may touch others which which then throws everything off.

Comment: But now that you have mentioned the word contour a nice algorithm has pop'd up Theo Pavlidis' Algorithm will give it a go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution was a combination of the above answers as to truly speed it up not only did I need a new algorithm but I had to use hashsets to... I went with Theo Pavlidis' Algorithm

http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/theo.html

Unfortunately on its own the algorithm could not beat an element by element approach using hash-sets, however incorporating hash-sets into the algorithm produced a 62% speed increase. Its also not a difficult method to apply hence why I've only included the page above.

Cheers everyone who helped.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put the answer for future reference.

Comment: No problem if anyone is after some code, I have written this http://sapphireprojects.com/blog/2013/04/28/contour-tracing-theo-pavlidis-algorithm/

Comment: Had a bit of a site overhaul, the article and code can now be found here http://scottalexander.co/theo-palvids-algorithm/

Answer (score 2):

I would try to make some kind of "edge detection" algorithm.

Say you go down from top to bottom in the middle of the image until you hit an edge, then you can follow this edge by scanning the 8 pixels surroundnig you and work your way around the object like this. On each position you check if your current coordinates are outside your bounding box, and increase as required.

Comment: It is a nice idea, however things can get messy if an object inside has a pixel distance of zero where an edge touches.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, where you break out when you've got the first unfound pixel and start following the edge.  But my approach only tells you you've got an edge, and it could be an interior void (as depicted).  So I have no good way to know when I'm done.  At least you know you've got the outside edge.

Comment: It gets even more nasty when the object doesnt have a "closed edge". The touching borders problem could solved by always choosing the most "away from center" path. I'm sure somewhere online is a good algorithm for this, and any proper algorithm is surely to beat the brute-force approach.

Comment: An away from center path may just work... I'll give it a quick go.

Answer (score 1):

One performance improvement would be to use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>`. That would speed up the check tremendously.

Comment: Well it has increased the speed of my process by about 60%, still a bit too slow but thanks for introducing me to hashsets :)

Comment: The link you've provided is busted :(

Comment: @YuriyY.Yermilov There is no link in my answer...?